# How to make notifications with a time duration Android

Tags: android, date

The user will set two dates and time: Start Date, and End Date. and Time

Start Date and Time is when the notification start to pop up in the status bar and stays there until the END Date or when the user finish the task notified. I dont want the notification to be gone when the user click it. Only goes to the app.

For example:

**NOTIFICATIONS:**

Activity to be notified: TASK 1

Start Date: 10/01/2015

End Date: 10/03/2015

Time: 6:00 am.

[SET]

I dont know if this is possible. Im new in Android.

Comment: I'm not extremely versed in notifications, but I used [this example](http://karanbalkar.com/2013/07/tutorial-41-using-alarmmanager-and-broadcastreceiver-in-android/) to figure out how to send a notification after a period of time.

Comment: i have already tested it but it wont recognize this function -> notification.setLatestEventInfo();